# How to enable checkpoint feature with lambda/kinesis integration?

Tags: aws-cdk

In a recent article (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/optimizing-batch-processing-with-custom-checkpoints-in-aws-lambda/) there is a mention to enabling a checkpoint behavior DynamoDB/Kinesis integration.

I wonder if this is already available with the CDK, and if so how to enable it.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported at the moment.

Checking [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda-event-sources.DynamoEventSourceProps.html) there is no such option yet.  Opened an issue in github to try to get this going: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/12654